# How do you replicate this java interface in Swift?

Tags: java, ios, swift

I know in swift you use protocols, but you can't instantiate a protocol by itself like you can do with an interface in java. Here is an example in Java

```
restartGameButton.setOnClickListener(new GuiClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(float x, float y) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                restartScene();
                //I can put whatever code I want in here. 
                //This is great because I can embed this inside of another class
                //like a game scene.
            }
        });
```

Inside restartGameButton I have a variable that just holds the interface. In the setOnClickListener() I can create a new interface instance with the onClick() method asking to be implemented and pass it to restartGameButton. This allows you to add whatever code you want in the onClickMethod. How can you do this in Swift? Swift only seems to allow you use a protocol as essentially an exstention of an object...not cool.

Comment: Not cool?  What's not cool is Java using anonymous subclasses because it apparently took 20 years to add lambdas.  What's cool is that you can express this with an actual function `(Float, Float) -> ()` instead of some dinky object.

Comment: If you actually explain this in an answer I'll give you the point. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: You cannot instantiate interface in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use optional closure property.

```
class GameButton {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var onClickListener: ((x: Float, y: Float)->Void)?

    func click(){
        if let cb = self.onClickListener {
            cb(x: self.x, y: self.y)
        }
    }

    init(){
        x = 1
        y = 2
    }
}


var button = GameButton()

button.onClickListener = {
    (x: Float, y: Float)->Void in

    println(x)
    println(y)
}
```